# utf8mb4 Encoding error with phpMyAdmin and remote MySQL database

Tags: character-encoding

I am trying to use phpMyAdmin to access a remote MySQL database so I created a config.inc.php file (copying config.sample.inc.php) and added a server. Now this other server appear as an option in the login page but when connecting I receive this error: MySQL said #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'.
Is there a workaround?
Is there a configuration I can set?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 1115 (42000) : Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the following files:

```
<install path>/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php
<install path>/libraries/mysql_charsets.lib.php
```

And change all instances of 'utf8mb4' to 'utf8'.

It seems to have worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me also.  I hate the new phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 8):

OPEN

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\DatabaseInterface.class.php
```

search for `'utf8mb4'` and replace it with `'utf8'` in two consecutive lines like below

```
 $default_charset = 'utf8';
 $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've already edited the lines in the files mentioned in [RAHUL-BHOLA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086331/rahul-bhola) and [Shane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245074/shane)'s answers:

```
<install path>/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php
<install path>/libraries/mysql_charsets.lib.php
```

And are still getting this error, and you're exporting a database from one phpMyAdmin installation to another phpMyAdmin installation, you can fix the error by deleting the following line in the .sql export file:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force export as well. You must edit file:

```
<install path>/libraries/plugins/export/ExportSql.class.php
```

and comment out following (from line 740) :

```
if ($set_names == 'utf8' && PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION > 50503) {
    $set_names = 'utf8mb4';
}
```

This will force export in SQL to be what you want to be. But you must first do changes in files (as was mentioned before)

```
<install path>/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php
<install path>/libraries/mysql_charsets.lib.php
```

New forced encoding in phpmyadmin is a pain in ass, because not all web hosting do recent updates. Such a **stupid** design!

Answer (score 2):

There is an incompatibility with phpMyAdmin 4.1.x and MySQL <= 5.5

Install phpMyAdmin 4.0.x

Answer (score 2):

I found that changing a portion of code located in files such as:

`<install path>/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php
<install path>/libraries/plugins/export/ExportSql.class.php`

from

`PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503`

to

`PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  55503`

does the trick

Comment: It worked for me two, and it seems to me more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Use firefox, if You can live with that.

I got this error on only one database with Chrome. Firefox worked fine. Chrome even worked fine with a master/master replika of the faled database.

The edit in DatabaseInterface.class.php mentioned above solved the issue for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I  have update the sql file that I exported by replacing 
 `utf8mb4' to 'utf8'.`

It worked for me. It happens due to improper mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

Change at the time of export the old database:
Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with ->mysql 4

thats it