# ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I have a MySQL dump, which I tried to restore with:

```
mysql -u"username" -p"password" --host="127.0.0.1" mysql_db < mysql_db
```

However, this threw an error:

```
ERROR 1115 (42000) at line 3231: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

This is lines 3231-3233:

```
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_general_ci */ ;
```

I am using MySQL 5.1.69. How can I solve this error?

Comment: You have to look at you dump with a text editor to see what is corrupted. You will see what is the probem and if you can recover. What is the code at line 3231 (and around it) ?

Comment: From which version of mysql your dump? You restoring it either to different host or to different version, or both, right?

Comment: Yes Alexander I am trying to restore an another host dump. I dont know the version.

Comment: into which version are restoring? try install the latest.

Comment: using version - 5.1.69

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your version does not support that character set, I believe it was `5.5.3` that introduced it. You should upgrade your mysql to the version you used to export this file.

The error is then quite clear: you set a certain character set in your code, but your mysql version does not support it, and therefore does not know about it.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html :

> utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8

so maybe there is a chance you can just make it utf8, close your eyes and hope, but that would depend on your data, and I'd not recommend it.

Comment: Simply changed utf8mb4 to utf8.It's working fine. Thanks @Nanne :-)

Comment: Definitely does **not** work in my case to simply change to utf8 - ended up with funky / junk characters throughout.

Comment: Well, obviously that could be the case -> your obvious sollutions is to re-encode your data from utf8mb4 to something your database supports OR to update your database to a version that supports your dataset.

Comment: yes in my case in localhost for old wamp it works when changed: `utf8mb4` to `utf8` editing file and inported again to mysql

Answer (score 30):

You can try:

Open sql file by text editor find and replace all

```
utf8mb4 to utf8
```

Import again.

Comment: Here's the linux command for that: 
sed -i 's/utf8mb4/utf8/g' dump.sql

Answer (score 9):

This can help:

```
mysqldump --compatible=mysql40 -u user -p DB > dumpfile.sql
```

PHPMyAdmin has the same MySQL compatibility mode in the 'expert' export options. Although that has on occasions done nothing.

If you don't have access via the command line or via PHPMyAdmin then editing the

```
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
```

bit to read `'utf8'` only, is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering the question - as I didn't find any of them complete. As nowadays  **Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'** is quite prevalent as lot of deployments have MySQL less then 5.5.3 (version in which utf8mb4 was added).

---

The error clearly states that you don't have `utf8mb4` supported on your stage db server.

**Cause**: probably locally you have `MySQL` version 5.5.3 or greater, and on stage/hosted VPS you have MySQL server version less then 5.5.3

The `utf8mb4` character sets was added in MySQL 5.5.3.

> `utf8mb4` was added because of a bug in MySQL's `utf8` character set.
>   MySQL's handling of the utf8 character set only allows a maximum of 3
>   bytes for a single codepoint, which isn't enough to represent the
>   entirety of Unicode (Maximum codepoint = `0x10FFFF`). Because they
>   didn't want to potentially break any stuff that relied on this buggy
>   behaviour, `utf8mb4` was added. [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

From [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036213/1115-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4/38995455#38995455):

---

**Verification**:
To verify you can check the current character set and collation for the DB you're importing the dump from - [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is/38996782#38996782)?

---

**Solution 1**: Simply upgrade your MySQL server to 5.5.3 (at-least) - for next time be conscious about the version you use locally, for stage, and for prod, all must have to be same. A suggestion - in present the default character set should be utf8mb4.

**Solution** 2 (not recommended): Convert the current character set to utf8, and then export the data - it'll load ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just open your sql file with a text editor and search for 'utf8mb4' and replace with utf8.I hope it would work for you

Comment: Really bad solution as you may lose some data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe whole database + tables + fields should have the same charset??!

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE `politicas` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  -------------------------------------^here!!!!!!!!!!!
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  -------------------------------------------------^here!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: I already solve the problem, Thanks for your answer. This may help to others.

Answer (score 0):

As some suggested here, replacing `utf8mb4` with `utf8` will help you resolve the issue. IMHO, I used `sed` to find and replace them to avoid losing data. In addition, opening a large file into any graphical editor is potential pain. My MySQL data grows up 2 GB. The ultimate command is

```
sed 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8_unicode_ci/g' original-mysql-data.sql > updated-mysql-data.sql
sed 's/utf8mb4/utf8/g' original-mysql-data.sql > updated-mysql-data.sql
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade the server, I was able to get rid of the error by downgrading the client's ODBC Connector to 5.3.8

Answer (score -1):

*Open your mysql file any edit tool*

find

> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

change

> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

Save and upload ur mysql.