# Can't launch phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

For some reason I can't launch pHp myadmin from XAMPP, I've tried different versions uninstalling and re installing wont launch. Give me the following error..

```
Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

Any idea? Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 1115 (42000) : Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4-in-mysql)

Comment: Is this the phpMyAdmin version that was packaged with that XAMPP version? As in, did you install your own phpMyAdmin outside of XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of MySQL is too old for your version of phpMyAdmin. See the [release history](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/news.php) for phpMyAdmin version 4.2.3.

Either upgrade MySQL or downgrade phpMyAdmin.

Comment: How do I upgrade mySQL?

Comment: Since you are using XAMPP, you should rather upgrade XAMPP. The latest one should work

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `utf8mb4` with `utf8` should work.

`utf8mb4` is a superset of `utf8`.