# Importing Database Causes Character Set Error

Tags: sql, import, character-encoding, mysql

I have an SQL dump and I want to import it. First, I tried this in terminal:

```
mysql -u root -ppass
create database db_name character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
mysql -u root -ppass db_name < dump.sql
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR 1253 (42000) at line 23: COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

So, I guess that means the dump I'm trying to import is decoded in `latin1`.

Then, I opened the SQL dump and looked at it. I saw this line:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So, I did this:

```
mysql -u root -ppass
create database db_name character set latin1 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

I guess the database dump file is broken. It's character set or encoding is not right I guess. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

What must I do to import this database? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are right, but you must change your MySQL settings to avoid the error:

- Edit this file:

  `sudo nano -c /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- Add these character settings:

  `character-set-server=utf8 
  collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
  init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
  init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci' 
  skip-character-set-client-handshake`
- Finally, restart MySQL daemon.

Comment: Why do I get an error if my commands are right? I've never seen an error like this before. Is this because of bad database design or something?

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville As I said, the commands are right, the problem is in your MySQL settings. Did you edit that file I showed you ?

Comment: I did. I inserted those and restarted my mysql daemon using `sudo service mysql restart`. However, it still doesn't work.