# #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I have a local webserver running on my pc to which I use for local development. I'm now at the stage of exporting the database and importing onto my hosted VPS.

When exporting then importing I get the following error!

## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you exporting your data? What dumping tool or database manager app you use?

Comment: What MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions do you have (both local and hosted versions, please)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error clearly states that you don't have `utf8mb4` supported on your stage db server.

**Cause**: probably locally you have `MySQL` version `5.5.3` or greater, and on stage/hosted VPS you have `MySQL` server version less then `5.5.3`

The utf8mb4 character sets was added in MySQL 5.5.3.

> `utf8mb4` was added because of a bug in MySQL's `utf8` character set.
>   MySQL's handling of the `utf8` character set only allows a maximum of 3
>   bytes for a single codepoint, which isn't enough to represent the
>   entirety of Unicode (Maximum codepoint = `0x10FFFF`). Because they
>   didn't want to potentially break any stuff that relied on this buggy
>   behaviour, `utf8mb4` was added. [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

---

**Solution 1**:
Simply upgrade your MySQL server to 5.5.3 (at-least) - for next time be conscious about the version you use locally, for stage, and for prod, all must have to be same.
**A suggestion** - in present the default character set should be `utf8mb4`.

---

**Solution 2** (not recommended): Convert the current character set to `utf8`, and then export the data - it'll load ok.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get similar problems while using HeidiSQL which by default exports in utf8mb4 character encoding. Not all MySQL installations support this encoding and importing such data leads to similar error messages. My workaround then is to export data using phpMyAdmin, which exports in utf8. There are problably other tools and possible ways like manually editing dump file, converting it from utf8mb4 to utf8 (if needed) and changing `SET NAMES utf8mb4` to `SET NAMES utf8`. Utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8, so if you're absolutely sure, that your data is just utf8, then you can simply change `SET NAMES` in dump file to `utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Open sql file by text editor find and replace all

```
utf8mb4 to utf8
```

Import again.

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.