# Uploading DataBase (From Local) to MySQL (Live) - Character Set Issues

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Im having a similar problem to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036213/1115-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4).

I made a wordpress site locally through MAMP - I then exported the database and attempted to import on a remote server.

The first attempt bought up an error and after browsing solutions on here i have replaced the characterset **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** to **utf8_general_ci**, this didn't work and i got the same error on the live mysql after import, however i did see that on the import of databases it asks for a specific characterset of the file utf8, which i then tried replacing utf8_general_ci with just utf-8, i get then the below error:

SQL query:

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf-8 */ MySQL said: Documentation

1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf'

Just to note, there are some tables importing from a specific booking plugin that has a characterset of utf8_general_cti.

Would updating the MAMP work? This is prompting me to update to new version but I wasn't sure if this would mess up my current work. Which maybe it already has!

Relates to questions on: [#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036213/1115-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4)

Comment: -- Table structure for table `codeneric_phmm_comments`
--CREATE TABLE `codeneric_phmm_comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `wp_user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `wp_author_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4
MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4'

Comment: Hi just the above some information after trying to edit the characteset to what was in the .config file to utf8mb4

Comment: Might be better suited for research on https://dba.stackexchange.com/