# databases disappeared from phpmyadmin after database collation change

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After changing the collation in phpmyadmin for several databases, I can't see them anymore in chrome and explorer. If a use the command SHOW DATABASES in the command line, they are all displayed.

In Firefox, the following error is thrown:

SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';

## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

This is my first post, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I had already read Q&A in [ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4), but it didn't solve my problem.

The mysql version I'm using is 5.6.17, and the character set is supported from version 5.3.3, so updating wouldn't help. I'm using wamp 2.5 with Mysql 5.6.17, Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12.

And I get the error simply accessing http://localhost/phpmyadmin (not executing any sql) after my update, so the problem seems to be already commited. It's quite confusing that the error message is displayed only in Firefox while other browsers simply hide some databases and show the others.

Executing 'SELECT default_collation_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;' in command line brought me these results:

utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_spanish_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_spanish_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_spanish_ci
utf8_general_ci
latin1_swedish_ci
utf8_spanish_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
latin1_swedish_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci

In PhpMyAdmin, the SCHEMATA table only shows ¡three! results:
One for 'information_schema', another for 'mysql' and the last one for one of my databases. The others are not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4)

Comment: Literally the first result on a google search for "1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'" brings up that specific Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Seth, but as I explain in my edition, the post you link didn't help.

Comment: you can't just stop at the first answer, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38259689/2036035)

Comment: Hi snb. I saw that answer but I have no sql to edit. The error appears in my phpmyadmin homepage.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I discovered there where two instances of mysql running on my server.

Phpmyadmin was using a 32 bits old version while the mysql command line was linked to the 64 bits one. I stopped the old one and now everything runs ok.